# jQuery an aspect ratio of an image with 100% width for responsive height

Tags: jquery, html, responsive-slides

I'd like to have a slideshow fill the screen height and width, but keep it's aspect ratio for the vertical slide effect. It would have to crop some of its (very wide) width on smaller screens and stretch both ways on very large screens. Is there a calculation that would determine the height of the #slideshow window and keep some aspect ratio? My verbose media queries are getting tiresome and reduce the height too much. You can see the problem as you scale the window at http://apurch.jvonhausen.com.

I saw a close answer at: [Image size calculation by keeping aspect ratio with different screen resolutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14197740/image-size-calculation-by-keeping-aspect-ratio-with-different-screen-resolutions) , but I think this is java, not script.

Comment: Your URL provided is reducing the height perfectly... To keep the ratio on a wide image, resizing the screen horizontally will make it very small in height...

Comment: Thank you. It took a lot of media queries to adjust at the appropriate screen width. I was hoping to learn a calculation that would be better – shorter. And, that I could crop the width at small sizes to keep the height larger.